# Help with creating an object out of xml data with nested elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<stop>
<code>2222222</code>
<code_short>E2217</code_short>
<name_fi>Konemies</name_fi>
<name_sv>Maskinbyggaren</name_sv>
<city_fi>Espoo</city_fi>
<city_sv>Esbo</city_sv>
<lines>
  <node>2010  1:Puolarmetsä</node>
  <node>2010K 1:Puolarmetsä</node>
  <node>2052  2:Hämevaara</node>
  <node>2103  1:Pohjois-Tapiola</node>
  <node>2103T 1:Pohjois-Tapiola</node>
  <node>2506  1:Pohjois-Tapiola</node>
  <node>2512A 2:Malmin asema</node>
  <node>2550  2:Itäkeskus, lait. 22</node>
  <node>5510  2:Vantaankoski</node>
</lines> </stop>
```

What I want is to use LINQ to create a List

where a Stop is:

```
public class Stop
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string shortCode { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

    public IList<string> lines { get; set; }

    public Stop()
    {
        lines = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this with LINQ ?

This LINQ gives me a List of Stops

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

        var stop = (from node in xdoc.Element("response").Elements("node")
                    select new Stop
                    {
                        code = node.Element("code").Value,
                        shortCode = node.Element("code_short").Value,
                        name = node.Element("name").Value,
                        city = node.Element("city").Value
                    });
```

**But how do I handle the lines ? Ideas ? Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var stop = (from node in xdoc.Descendants("stop")
            select new Stop
            {
                code = node.Attribute("code").Value,
                shortCode = node.Attribute("code_short").Value,
                name = node.Attribute("name").Value,
                city = node.Attribute("city").Value,
                lines = node.Element("lines")
                            .Elements("node")
                            .Select(x => (string) x)
                            .ToList()
            });
```

The above code also demonstrates an alternative way of converting an `XElement` to a string - using a cast instead of the `.Value` property. If the `XElement` is null, the result of the cast will be null, whereas the result of `.Value` will be an exception. If it's valid for the element to be missing, using `.Value` is good because it will cause an error as soon as the bad data is detected; for "optional" elements, the cast is an easy way to tolerate missing values.

Comment: Error 2 The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @digitalSurgeon: Small typo - fixed now.